# Javaによるコードクローン（重複コード）の発見ツールでおすすめなものありますか？

Tags: java

## やりたいこと

Javaによるコードクローン（重複コード）の発見をしたいと考えています。
PMDは検出力が弱い様に感じましたので、他のお勧めなツールや検討に値するツールがありましたら教えてください。

CCFinder（http://www.ccfinder.net/ccfinderxos-j.html）も有名な様ですが、UIが直感的でない様に感じました。こちらの勘所もご存じの方いらっしゃいましたら、教えて頂けると幸いです。

## 背景

- プロジェクトの規模は、1k人月～5k人月規模です。
- Webアプリケーションの開発

---

コメントありがとうございます。
たとえば検出したいコードの一例として下記の様なものがあります。
（サンプルは同一クラス内のメソッドです）
重複コードとしてばっちり下記を捕らえてくれないように思います。

```
（略）
public void code1() {
    String hoge = null;
    hoge.length();
    int[] a = {34, 21, 13, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0};
    System.out.println(a[0]);
}

public void code2() {
    String hoge = null;
    hoge.length();
    int[] b = {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34};
    System.out.println(b[9]);
}
（略）
```

Comment: PMDのCopy Paste Detector (CPD)はCIツールなどでもよく利用されていて、私もJenkins上で利用しているのですが、検出力が弱いとはあまり感じたことがありません。具体的にどのあたりに検出力の弱さを感じられますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。まだサンプルコードで試している段階ですが、例を追記しました。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: PMDでの重複コード検出は簡単には文字列のパターンマッチなので、サンプルのようなコードは重複とは検出できないですね。無償のものでサンプルコードを重複と判断してくれるようなツールは申し訳ないのですが知りません。有償のものだとコベリティ（http://www.coverity.com/html_ja/）あたりが有名でしょうか。使ったことが無いのでわからないのですが、もしかしたらサンプルコードを重複と判断してくれるかもしれません。

Comment: なるほど。パターンマッチアルゴリズムなのですね。リサーチ不足でした。教えて頂きましてありがとうございます。Coverityのツールもありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CI で使えない IDE の機能で恐縮なのですが，[IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) (有料) に[重複コードの検出機能](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/analyzing-duplicates.html)があり，上記サンプルコードも検出できます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

- 使い方：メインメニュー Analyze > Locate Duplicates から実行します
- 分析の単位は，全プロジェクトの全ファイルに可能です
- 検出の粒度は，ローカル変数，フィールド，メソッド，型，リテラル（文字）をオプション選択することができます

  - 上記サンプルコードの重複検出はリテラル (Anonymize Literals) オプションを有効にすると検出できます
- 対応言語は，[Java 以外にも Javascript，HTML，CSS](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/code-duplication-analysis-settings.html) 等があります

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

- IntelliJ IDEA 15 より，[コード記述中にリアルタイムで重複コードを検出&表示](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/08/intellij-idea-15-eap-adds-on-the-fly-code-duplicates-detection/)してくれますので，コード品質担当者でない開発担当者も，開発中に重複コードに気付ける仕組みが最初からあります

  - 若干鬱陶しいぐらいリアルタイムで重複コードが検出されます…
- 重複コード分析結果は HTML で出力可能です

  - 出力された HTML に文字コードの指定がないため，日本語が文字化けしてしまいます
  - <meta charset="UTF-8"> を出力された HTML のヘッダに追加すれば，文字化けが解消します

IntelliJ の回し者のようになってしまいましたが，重複検出が強力なのでおすすめします。

Comment: ありがとうございます！CIが使えないのが残念ですが、検討価値がありそうです！